# Problems serving static files in CherryPy 3.1

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm having some trouble serving a static XML stylesheet to accompany some dynamically generated output from a CherryPy web app. Even my test case serving a static text file fails.

Static file `blah.txt` is in the `/static` directory in my application root directory.

In my main site file (conesearch.py contains the CherryPy ConeSearch page-handler class):

```
import conesearch
cherrypy.config.update('site.config')
cherrypy.tree.mount(conesearch.ConeSearch(), "/ucac3", 'ucac3.config')
...
```

And in `site.config` I have the following options:

```
[/]
tools.staticdir.root: conesearch.current_dir

[/static]
tools.staticdir.on: True
tools.staticdir.dir: 'static'
```

where `current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` in `conesearch.py`

However, my simple test page (taken straight from http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/StaticContent) fails with a 404:

```
def test(self):
        return """
        <html> 
        <head>
        <title>CherryPy static tutorial</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <a href="/static/blah.txt">Link</a>
        </body>
        </html>"""
test.exposed = True
```

It is trying to access 127.0.0.1:8080/static/blah.txt, which by my reckoning should be AOK. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Cheers,

Simon

Answer (score 4):

`cherrypy.config.update` should only receive a single-level dictionary (mostly `server.*` entries), but you're passing it a multi-level dictionary of settings that should really be per-app (and therefore passed to `tree.mount`).

Move those `[/]` and `[/static]` sections from your `site.config` file to your `ucac3.config` file, and it should work fine.

Comment: Oh, and change `<a href="/static/blah.txt">Link</a>` to `<a href="/ucac3/static/blah.txt">Link</a>`. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I serve static files like this:

```
config = {'/static':
                {'tools.staticdir.on': True,
                 'tools.staticdir.dir': PATH_TO_STATIC_FILES,
                }
        }

cherrypy.tree.mount(MyApp(), '/', config=config)
```

Comment: Nope, still no joy I'm afraid. Thanks though. Still getting a 404 on `blah.txt`. If I understand CherryPy config dicts/files correctly this should work exactly the same as the config files I have set up above right?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup.  Let's say that I want the root of my site to be at http://mysite.com/site and that the root of my site/app is at */path/to/www*.

I have the following config settings in my server.cfg and am finding my static files without a problem:

```
[global]
...
app.mount_point = '/site'
tools.staticdir.root = '/path/to/www/'
[/static]
tools.staticdir.on = True
tools.staticdir.dir = 'static'
```

I'm serving up dojo files, etc, from within the static directory without a problem, as well as css.  I'm also using genshi for templating, and using the cherrypy.url() call to ensure that my other URLs are properly set.  That allows me to change app.mount_point and have my links update as well.